# Rank of free abelian subgroups in integral linear groups

Tags: group-theory, matrices

What is the maximal rank of a free abelian subgroup in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I expect it's $n-1$.

Comment: Does the following make sense? Take $\mathbb{Z}^r \subseteq \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$. Then there exists a prime $p$ such that under the projection $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_p)$, the group $\mathbb{Z}^r$ goes to a product of $r$ non-trivial finite cyclic groups. Now try to argue in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_p)$ that $r\leq n-1$.

Comment: That doesn' quite work, because ${\rm GL}_n(p)$ has abelian subgroups of rank $n$. But by moving to a subgroup of index 2, you can assume that it is in ${\rm SL}_n({\mathbb Z})$, and the maximal rank of abelian subgroups of ${\rm SL}_n(p)$ is $n-1$.